# White background of widgets within a notebook tab

Tags: python, widget, gtk, glade

I have this problem in glade, when I create various widgets or labels within a notebook tab, they have a white background, not the usual gray one.

Fig1 and Fig2 demonstrate this. but Fig2 widgets are not within a notebook tab.

[image]

How can I fix the background colour within a notebook tab?

(Without changing css or anything within the code in the program.)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this with CSS after all.

```
#Code in python program

    estiloVentana = self.ventana.get_style_context()
    cssProv = Gtk.CssProvider()
    cssProv.load_from_path('style.css')
    screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
    estiloVentana.add_provider_for_screen(screen, cssProv,
                              Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

and the css file.

```
#CSS code
GtkNotebook {
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
```

That's all, hope someone might find this usefull.

Comment: This is not an valid answer since it requires **changing css or anything within the code in the program.** (although it solved part of the problem)